# Aligning images in a DIV

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to align three images in a class div into a straight horizontal line.

```
<div class="topimages">
  <img src="code/images/image_personallogo.png" alt="personallogo">

  <img src="code/images/image_propercorn.png" alt="propercorn">

  <img src="code/images/image_christmas.png" alt="christmascard">
  </div><!--top images-->
```

and the CSS so far

```
.topimages {
  display: table;
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}



.topimages img {
    width:319px;
    height:319px;
}
```

So the problem is that the images are almost perfectly aligned except that there is different space between the second and third image than between the first and second image.  This is what I am talking about : http://postimg.org/image/y00x4nvtr/

Anyone knows what cause this and how I can fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: try to remove `display: table;`

Comment: As @FabrizioCalderan suggested, remove `display: table;` from the `.topimages` selector and try adding `display: inline-block` to the the `topimages img` selector

Comment: Seems still aligned in my test, can you explain more about what you mean?

Comment: Can you see how there is more space between the first and second image and smaller between the second and third. What I mean is that the space between the images is not equal. I'm not sure if I'm explaining myself very well.

I just tried the inline-block and it still looks the same.

Comment: @YanaVelikova, seems ok to me, IF you really want this: http://jsfiddle.net/k27xby07/ ?  319x3 = 957, your container is 1024px...

Comment: @YanaVelikova then it's probably some margin that hasn't anything to do with this code. Can you link to your page, or include some more code?

Comment: @YanaVelikova the code you provided here doesn't produce abnormal space between the images, so there must be other styles, do you have a live example?

Comment: 957 container seems to be fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

The nicest way is to use a **table** with one **tr**:

HTML:

```
<table id="myImages">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="code/images/image_christmas.png" alt="christmascard" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="code/images/image_propercorn.png" alt="propercorn" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="code/images/image_christmas.png" alt="christmascard" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

To change margin in a table, you must use **border-collapse** and **border-spacing**

CSS:

```
#myImages {
    border: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 0px auto;

    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 20px;
}

#myImages img {
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
}
```

In a table or (display: table) there is no need to set a whole width to use **margin: 0 auto** to center the element. The width comes from the width of the elements within. And from paddings and margins.

https://jsfiddle.net/ka827L97/